# How to read a symlink in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, symlink, fs

I want to read a symlink, and get the details of the link itself, *not* the contents of the linked file. How do I do that in Node, in a cross-platform way?

I can detect symlinks easily using `lstat`, no problem. Once I know the path of the file, and that it is a symlink though, how can I read it? `fs.readFile` always reads the target file, or throws an error for reading a directory for links to directories.

There is a `fs.constants.O_SYMLINK` constant, which in theory solves this on OSX, but it seems to be undefined on both Ubuntu & Windows 10.

Comment: I hope my answer helps, I'm not sure why you would want to read the raw link file on windows / linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have determined that the file is a symlink try this:

```
fs.readlink("./mysimlink", function (err, linkString) { 
         // .. do some error handling here .. 
         console.log(linkString) 
});
```

Confirmed as working on Linux.

You could then use `fs.realpath()` to turn it into a full path.  Be aware though that `linkString` can be just a filename or relative path as well as a fully qualified path so you may have to get `fs.realpath()` for the symlink, determine its directory part and prefix it to `linkString` before using `fs.realpath()` on it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think that's perfect

Comment: Regarding the statement above about running fs.realpath() on the symlink first, in my Node.js v10.16.0 it did not return the full path to the symlink.  Instead, running fs.realpath() on a symlink returned the full path to the *target* of the symlink without needing to run fs.readlink() at all.  This seems fine for my purposes but seems problematic if someone wants the actual full path to the symlink.  This is also the behavior on Python's os.path.realpath().

Comment: On Windows when I point this to a `.lnk` file, I just get `Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink`

Comment: @tom I think this is a linux only function.  However, are you pointing to the file with or without the extension?

Comment: @Voltaire, I tried both. I ended up creating the links with the command line with `mklink /D`. It works the same as on Linux then. Friend of mine who's very knowledgable in Windows told me that the `.lnk` files are actually files storing metadata for the links like arguments and the icons and therefore only work with windows explorer and are not actual links. He told me to use the command line for creating real links and then everything should work as expected, which it does. It's transparent then as it should be,

Comment: `readlink()` is not a Unix-only function. It's also implemented for Windows. But only for real symlinks on Windows, which are rarely used and require Admin privileges even to make. The files with `.lnk` extensions are not real symlinks but are Windows "shortcuts", which are something for Explorer, not for the filesystem, like aliases on the Mac. Cygwin however provides custom versions of all the symlink functions that treats `.lnk` shortcuts as symlinks. Either because they work on non-NT Windows, because they work on non-NTFS drives, or because they don't need admin privs.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same issue: sometimes `fs.readlink` returns a relative path, sometimes it returns an absolute path.
(proper error handling not implemented to keep things simple)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pathPckg = require('path');

async function getTarLinkOfSymLink(path){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readlink(path, (err, tarPath)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message);
                return resolve('');
            }
            const baseSrcPath = pathPckg.dirname(path);
            return resolve( pathPckg.resolve(baseSrcPath, tarPath) );
        });
    });
}

// usage:
const path = '/example/symbolic/link/path';
const tarPath = await getTarLinkOfSymLink(path);
```

The code works if the symbolic link is either a file or a directory/folder - tested on Linux